# fastest way to count occurrences of partial list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, performance

What is the fastest way to count an element occurrences from a start position till a stop position.

```
 list = [a,b,c,c,d,c....] can be very long
 count(list,c, from = 2, till = 4) = 2.
```

we could do

```
 counter = 0
 for i in range(startpos, endpos):
        if symbol == list[i]:
            counter+= 1
```

or we could do

```
list[startpos:endpos].count(symbol)
```

However this still looks slower than the first option and will copy a big part of the list

Since strings have a count function like this we could join the list to a string and than use the build in count fuction, however since the list is big the conversion to a string doesn't seem like a faster approach.

Is there any faster more pythonic way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a pure Python solution, converting your first option into a generator expression in a `sum` function would likely be the most efficient solution for a really large list:

```
sum(1 for i in range(startpos, endpos) if list[i] == symbol)
```

Other options such as iterating from the beginning of the list, which wastes large amounts of time iterating out of the desired range, or slicing, which involves creating a copy, would not be nearly as efficient when the list is really large.

If you don't mind using `numpy`, however, you can create a `numpy` array instead of a list so that you can slice it without copying items (`numpy` creates a view of the array when you slice), and then use the `sum` method to count the number of items in the slice equaling the desired value:

```
import numpy as np

... # create your very large numpy array as lst

print(np.sum(lst[startpos:endpos] == symbol))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a generator and a range to check if an enumerate index is inside your range:

```
a = 2
pos = range(5,15)
d = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,]
total = sum(elem == a for idx,elem in enumerate(d) if idx in pos)

print(total)
```

This won't copy the list but it will iterate the full original one. Checking if `idx` is in `range` is fast.

Unrolling the loop would alow for a break - if fasteness is ultra critical, you should timeit your approaches:

```
maxpos = max(pos)
minpos = min(pos)
for idx,elem in enumerate(d):
    if idx < minpos:
        continue
    elif idx > pos:
        break

    # check elem and counts something up
        continue
```

This might or might not be faster if you only test a small amount of your list - it wont do much if you thest the last elements in your list, but if your list is huge and your target area is "front"ish -the break might save you some cycles

Comment: `lst[start:end].count(elem)` is better and faster than `enumerate` version(*almost 10x times but I guess that dependent on the range*) but your alternative is doing the same with no extra space as `list[start:end].count`.+1. [`timeit` results](https://repl.it/repls/OrangeredPrimeDemands)

Comment: "better and faster" depends on the data you feed it. If you have 5 billion datapoints out of a sublist of 5.2 datapoints, - copying those 5 billion datapoints and counting afterwards might be more costly then iterating them -thats why I mentioned `timeit`-ing it. for ease of reading and good c++ implementation the copy.count() variant is probably what I would go for 99/100 times.

Comment: The premise of the question is a very long list, so iterating from the beginning of the list can be rather inefficient if the desired range is near the end of the list since cycles are wasted in iterating outside of the range.

Comment: Totally agreed. When the data's really large. I would use the second approach you mentioned or use *NumPy* arrays in the first place for handling such large data.

Comment: than my first solution would bet faster, this is very slow, the numpy solution looks like the right way to do this. thx for replying

Comment: @blh your way of using the generator sum is better :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
from collections import Counter
print(Counter(my_list[start:end]))
```

Your can convert the `Counter` object to dict if you prefer:

```
occurrences = dict(Counter(my_list[start:end]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add up to blhsing's answer, the generator expression could be slightly less verbose:

```py
sum(list[i] == symbol for i in range(startpos, endpos))
```